# Spring RmiExporter service fails after successful startup

Tags: java, spring, rmi, lsof

I'm experiencing a situation where an RMI Service configured using Spring's `RmiServiceExporter` is starting up just fine, and is usable for a while - then after some unknown amount of time, the service is unavailable even though the java process for that Spring context is still running.

At the moment the work around is to reboot the java process, but this is hardly acceptable in a production environment. I cannot figure out, or even begin to guess, why this might be happening, or what to look for that might be going wrong. No S/O or Google search has been useful, because all I find are examples of `RmiServiceExporter` failing to start at all, not starting ok and then failing later on. Any clue at all would be useful.

Output of `lsof | head -1;lsof | grep 1197`, **before** the service fails:

```
COMMAND     PID       USER   FD      TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF      NODE NAME
java       6882     ubuntu  176u     IPv6           54677985      0t0       TCP *:1197 (LISTEN)
```

Service-side Spring config:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiServiceExporter">
    <property name="serviceName" value="MyRmiService" />
    <property name="service" ref="myService" />
    <property name="serviceInterface" value="package.MyService" />
    <property name="registryPort" value="${my.rmi.port}" />
</bean>
```

Client-side Spring config:

```
<bean id="remoteService" class="org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="serviceUrl" value="rmi://${my.rmi.host}:${my.rmi.port}/MyRmiService"/>
    <property name="serviceInterface" value="package.MyService"/>
    <property name="lookupStubOnStartup" value="false"/>
    <property name="refreshStubOnConnectFailure" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

Client-side stacktrace, **after** the service fails (`lsof` reports nothing):

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.remoting.RemoteLookupFailureException: Lookup of RMI stub failed; nested exception is java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: rmiservice.host; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiClientInterceptor.lookupStub(RmiClientInterceptor.java:215)
    at org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiClientInterceptor.getStub(RmiClientInterceptor.java:237)
    at org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiClientInterceptor.invoke(RmiClientInterceptor.java:257)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at $Proxy61.serviceMethod(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:191)
    at package.Client.main(Client.java:47)
Caused by: java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: rmiservice.host; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:601)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:198)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:184)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(UnicastRef.java:322)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi.Naming.lookup(Naming.java:84)
    at org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiClientInterceptor.lookupStub(RmiClientInterceptor.java:200)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:351)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:213)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:478)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:375)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:189)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:22)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:128)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:595)
    ... 17 more
```

Comment: Similar situation occur in my case with JDBC connection pool and we found a firewall / router setting disconnects idle TCP connection after certain period. Either check your TCP / firewall setting, or find a way to keep the connection exchanging packets somehow.

Comment: I will look into this as a possible line of attack. I'm not sure it fits the symptoms, which is that the java process continues to run, but it stops listening on port 1197 (the RMI port)

Comment: System level socket timeout perhaps?

Comment: How could I check for that? Might be an error in an OS log? Running on Ubuntu Linux. Also wonder where that might be set, as apparently Java has infinite timeout according to http://magnus-k-karlsson.blogspot.co.uk/2010/10/default-timeout-value-for-standard-java.html

Comment: You can google it, for example http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-increasing-or-decreasing-tcp-sockets-timeouts.html

Answer (score 0):

Which web server you are using ?

If it is Apache Tomcat, then add to `CATALINA_OPTS` variable

```
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=10.0.34.11
```

in `catalina.sh` file and then export `CATALINA_OPTS` variable.